# How to automatically log out a user and redirect him to a login page with a custom message in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

When any page is viewed, I need to make sure that the user ID is in a custom database table, and if the id is not present there, I want to log the user out and not allow him to see any content. I also want to display a custom message on the login page saying "You are not authorised to see this blog."

I tried doing this with some of the wp logout/redirect functions, but I want this to be automatic on all pages across the wp site. Also I don't know how to sent the custom message to the login page. I guess I could just set a POST value or something like that and modify the login page to check if that value is present.

Any help or tips on how to do this *properly* would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try following

Put the code below in your theme templates.

```
    //Logic for checking whether the ID exists or not
    if(empty($id)){
       wp_logout();
    }
```

Put following in your function.php

```
    //When the user is logged out redirect him/her to the login page with a custom parameter
    add_action('wp_logout','go_home');
    function go_home(){
      wp_redirect( '/wp-login.php?action=logout&custom-logout=yes' );
      exit();
    }

    //If the custom parameter is set display the message on the login screen
    if(!empty($_GET['custom-logout']) && strtolower($_GET['custom-logout']) == "yes"){
     function custom_login_message() {
         $message = '<p class="message">Add your message here...</p><br />';
         return $message;
     }
     add_filter('login_message', 'custom_login_message');
    }
```